# Error when importing Dictionary to another file

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

so i need to use a dictionary within another file but am getting an error when importing the file. my file is called "Final Chess Game.py" with the spaces.

here is how im calling it:

```
from Final Chess Game import pieces
```

"pieces" is my dict.

Im getting an error on "Chess" within the import, do i have to change the name of the file or is there any other way of calling the dictionary from the final chess game file?

Comment: could you send me a link for the full source on github

Comment: alright now send me what's inside Final_Chess_game

Comment: Also tell me what is the goal of this code

Comment: and tell me why Chessboard has to inherit tk.Frame

Comment: i can send u the main frame of the chessboard class but cannot send you the whole code as it is for my final project. i can however send you the main class the dictionary is being used from.

Comment: why does it inherit tk.frame

Comment: also in sendDict you forgot a parenthesis when instantiating the class

Comment: def sendDict(self):
    a = Final_Chess_Game.ChessBoard()
     serializedDict = json.dumps(a.pieces)
     print(serializedDict)
     return a.pieces`

Comment: tbh, i used the GUI from online and have no idea why it inherits tk.frame

Comment: in sendDict you have to actually instantiate the chessboard by adding the parentheses

Comment: your code creates a new chessboard each time is that what you want?

Comment: i know, i tried that and it needed a "parent" argument, i tried several things but none worked.

Comment: basically, i am creating online chess for my final project. i am using a dictionary to keep a record of the chess pieces and posisitons and would like to send it to another user over sockets to have the updated version of the dictionary. That is why i would like to import and use the dictionary.

Comment: Yeah so Chessboard is a gui, the parent would be from tkinter, you'd have to do something like `root = tk.Tk()`, and pass root in as parent

Comment: Your code does not save the chessboard, it deletes it and creates a new one each time

Comment: its saying "tk" isnt defined, ive imported tkinter and done this `root = tk.Tk()` and `a = Final_Chess_Game.ChessBoard(root)`

Comment: import tkinter as tk

Comment: its works, thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: if you need any more help just hit me up with a comment

Comment: thanks man, the only problem i got is actually using the data but i think i'll search that up. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply bad practice to have spaces in your import. Python thinks that you are trying to import Final and reads a syntax error when you get to Chess. You should rename your file to something without spaces.

If you absolutely want to import that file:

```
Final_Chess_Game = __import__("Final Chess Game")
```

Now you can call functions from Final Chess Game through `Final_Chess_Game.<functioname>`

If your chessboard class looks like this:

```
class ChessBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=70, color1="White", color2="lightgrey"):

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}
```

You cannot import a class variable without importing the whole class. You must import the whole chessboard. You can access the chessboard with:

```
Final_Chess_Game.ChessBoard
```

You cannot `self.pieces` without first creating an instance of the class. `self.pieces` is an instance variable, so each ChessBoard that you create has a `.pieces` variable.

Comment: Thank you, i just fixed it but got another error saying "cannot import name 'pieces", i tried self.pieces but that also did not work.

Comment: now its saying final chess game has no "pieces" attribute.

Comment: this is my dictionary within Finalchessgame file: "self.pieces = {}"

Comment: is pieces a function or a class?

Comment: if pieces has self that means that it is within a class... you have to import the whole class

Comment: `'class ChessBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=70, 
    color1="White", color2="lightgrey"):

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}`

Comment: @HAHAHAHAHA read the edit. You can't import an object variable. Object variables can be read after you have created an isntance of the particular object and start to modify the object's variables

Comment: Now it says ChessBoard has no attribute "pieces" :/, this is what im usign `Pieces = Final_Chess_Game.ChessBoard                                                    
        serializedDict = json.dumps(Pieces.pieces)`

Comment: So how would i use the dictionary from the other file?

Comment: Import chessboard make a chessboard. Use that chessboard's pieces dict

Comment: look send me the source i'll gladly revise if for you